# How can i call the 'My Order' file in 'My Dashboard' page?

Tags: magento, themes

I am making a custom theme in Magento. and I want to add a table of My orders in Main Account Dashboard page. How can i call 'Order.phtml' in 'Dashboard.phtml' ? Or any other way to do it.I Had tried `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('orders') ?>` in dashboard.phtml but it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated... Thank you ...

Comment: If you're new, try to learn basics before asking a single question. https://www.google.fr/search?q=magento+tutorials

Answer (score 1):

There are some settings for which page you want to see after Login into admin panel

You can do it by Navigating through Admin panel:

```
Step1: Login to admin panel
Step2: Go to System->Configuration
Step3: On left Hand Panel at last you will see Advance tab under it click on Admin Panel
Step4: Now under startup page Choose Orders under sales 
Step5: Now you can view your orders instead of dashboard
```

If confused you can see the screen shot below.

[link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/07d1ge0yf5)